# How to detect tabs or spaces in Emacs

Tags: indentation, tabs

By default I want all indentation (when I hit the `tab` key) to be 2 spaces.

However, when I am editing certain Python files (where I **can not** mix tabs and spaces) I would like to use whatever the existing indentation is.

Every time I open a file I see `Can’t guess python-indent-offset, using defaults: 4`

That warning and [answers like these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18778894/emacs-24-3-python-cant-guess-python-indent-offset-using-defaults-4/18780754) make me think that Emacs can guess the offset.  However, when I just edited a file that uses all tabs, pressing the `tab` key resulted in 4 spaces.

In my `init` file I do have the following:

`(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)`

Can somebody tell me if I really need to install `guess style` mode in order to switch between tabs and spaces based on what exists in the file?

Is there another way to allow tabs (even though I have disabled them by default)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> By default I want all indentation (when I hit the `tab` key) to be 2 spaces.

This can be achieved for many modes with settings such as

```el
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil
              tab-stop-list    ()
              tab-width        2)
```

> Every time I open a file I see `Can’t guess python-indent-offset, using defaults: 4`

The default indentation offset for `python.el` can be configured via the customisable variable `python-indent-offset`.

Whether `python.el` tries to guess the indentation offset can be controlled by the customisable variable `python-indent-guess-indent-offset`.

Whether `python.el` prints this message after guessing the indentation offset can be controlled by the customisable variable `python-indent-guess-indent-offset-verbose`.

> That warning and [answers like these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18778894/emacs-24-3-python-cant-guess-python-indent-offset-using-defaults-4/18780754) make me think that Emacs can guess the offset. However, when I just edited a file that uses all tabs, pressing the `tab` key resulted in 4 spaces.

This is probably because `python-mode` and `inferior-python-mode` from `python.el` set `indent-tabs-mode` to `nil` by default.

Note that "guessing the offset" and "inserting tabs or spaces" are not the same thing. Emacs (more specifically, `python.el`) can indeed do the former, but the latter does not seem like a very easy task to me and I am not familiar with a built-in means of achieving this. I suggest you consider the following options for setting `indent-tabs-mode`:

- Define your own convenience function which toggles `indent-tabs-mode`. For example:

  ```el
  (defun my-toggle-indent-tabs-mode ()
    "Toggle `indent-tabs-mode'."
    (interactive)
    (setq-local indent-tabs-mode (not indent-tabs-mode)))
  ```

  You can even bind this to a convenient key.
- Install [`python-mode.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ProgrammingWithPythonModeDotEl). It is more customisable than `python.el` and provides `indent-tabs-mode`-toggling commands like the one above.
- Use [file-local variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/File-Variables.html) to determine and, to an extent, enforce the desired style in certain files.
- Similarly with [directory-local variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html). See also [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Directory-Local-Variables.html).
- Add a custom function to `python-mode-hook` with your own logic for setting `indent-tabs-mode`, e.g. based on file name or contents.
- Install a third-party package which detects indentation style based on customisable heuristics, such as [dtrt-indent](https://github.com/jscheid/dtrt-indent). See also [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3726376/3084001).

> [do] I really need to install `guess style` mode

Yes, for the reasons outlined above I think you need to install a third-party package for automatic tab/space detection.

No, I would not recommend [guess-style](https://nschum.de/src/emacs/guess-style/), as it seems to be `cc-mode`-specific, and newer versions of `cc-mode` come with built-in style guessing.

Comment: Great answer. `dtrt-indent` was a good solution for me.

Comment: wow answer. I was looking for the `...-verbose` variable, to silence the warnings. Many thanks. (reposted to https://stackoverflow.com/a/51966682/1449460)

Comment: Does any of these packages implement caching of detected offset associated with a given source file? At least when that file hasn't changed since it was last edited in Emacs.

Comment: @Nordlöw The built-in `python-mode` conditionally tries to detect indentation whenever the mode is enabled.  I don't know about the others.