# How can you make conf-mode indent with tabs?

Tags: indentation, tabs

When I open a config file that has been indented with tabs, the mode shows as `(Conf[Space] WS)` and pressing `Tab` indents with spaces, even though the rest of the file is using tabs.

How can I change this mode to indent with tab characters instead?

I thought `[Space]` might have meant it was a minor mode, so I looked into changing the minor mode but the [list of minor modes in the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Minor-Modes.html) doesn't mention anything about a tab mode.

The [EmacsWiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MinorMode) mentions an `indent-tabs-mode` however this does not appear to be in version 25.1.1 that I am using.

I looked into `customize-mode` however I can't find anything in there about indenting.

Is there a setting to change `conf-mode` to indent with tabs instead?

**Update with suggestions from @Basil:**

`(setq indent-tabs-mode t)` has no effect.  After running it with `M-:`, pressing the tab key is the same as pressing the spacebar multiple times (enough to match the first non-leading space character on the previous line.)

Putting the `add-hook` code suggested by @Basil in my `init.el`, closing the buffer, reloading Emacs, then reopening the file, also has no effect.  Pressing the tab key is the same as pressing the spacebar multiple times.

`(setq tab-width N)` immediately changes the width of the existing tabs in the file.  On a line with no spaces on the line above it, setting `tab-width` to `2` makes the tab key insert two spaces, setting it to `8` makes the tab key equivalent to pressing the spacebar eight times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I thought [Space] might have meant it was a minor mode

The mode line lighter `Conf[Space]` corresponds to `conf-space-mode`, which is a major mode derived from `conf-mode` for editing space-separated configuration files (i.e. ones where key-value pairs are separated by arbitrary-length whitespace), such as `~/.ssh/config` under Unices. `conf-space-mode` has **nothing** to do with tabs vs spaces.

By the way, in graphical Emacs instances you can click on components of the mode line to get more information about them. There's probably a simple way to inspect this under a textual environment as well which eludes me.

`conf-mode` is interesting in that it is not actually a major mode. What it does is a pretty decent job of detecting the type of configuration syntax used in the current buffer before selecting a more specialised mode accordingly, such as `conf-unix-mode` or `conf-space-mode` in your case. See its documentation `C-h f conf-mode RET` or `M-x describe-function RET conf-mode RET` for more information.

> `indent-tabs-mode` [...] does not appear to be in version 25.1.1 that I am using

It most certainly does exist in your version, you are probably just looking in the wrong place because of its misleading name. If you were to type `M-x apropos RET indent-tabs-mode RET` or `C-h o indent-tabs-mode RET` or `M-x describe-symbol RET indent-tabs-mode RET` you would see that it is, in fact, a variable and not a major/minor mode.

> How can I change this mode to indent with tab characters instead?

You can usually toggle space/tab indentation in any normal/well-behaved mode via the buffer-local variable `indent-tabs-mode`. In order to enable tab indentation, set it to a non-`nil` value:

```el
(setq indent-tabs-mode t)
```

If, for example, you would like to default to tab indentation in `conf-mode`, you can set this in a corresponding mode hook:

```el
(add-hook 'conf-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (setq indent-tabs-mode t)))
```

You can replace `conf-mode-hook` with any other mode's hook, e.g. `conf-space-mode-hook`.

#### Update

As mentioned in the comments, another variable to play around with in combination with `indent-tabs-mode` is `indent-line-function`, which is the function called to actually perform the indentation. This variable is often set by the corresponding `major-mode`, but this is not the case in the `conf-mode` family. It defaults to `indent-relative`, which indents relative to the previous line, but a possibly more suitable value in this case would be `insert-tab`, which inserts either a literal tab character or `tab-width` many spaces, depending on the value of `indent-tabs-mode`. I recommend reading the documentation (and even viewing the source, if practical) for all aforementioned variables and functions. Here is a sample hook which performs the described change:

```el
(add-hook 'conf-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (setq indent-line-function #'insert-tab
                  indent-tabs-mode     t)))
```

---

See also the last parts of [this answer of mine](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/32943/15748) for some tab/space auto-detection pointers.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed helpful reply!  I had no idea I could click on the mode to see more options - never occurred to me to do so!  Unfortunately however, setting `indent-tabs-mode` seems to have no effect (with either `M-:` or putting the hook in my `init.el`) so does that mean `conf-mode` is not well-behaved?

Comment: @Malvineous Could you please update your answer to describe the expected and actual behaviour after setting `indent-tabs-mode`? My first guess would be that the setting is working, but spaces are being inserted instead of a tab character because the indentation offset is smaller than `tab-width`. What happens if you also `(setq tab-width N)`, where `N` is the number of spaces that constitute an indentation level?

Comment: @Malvineous I wrote "update your answer" but meant to say "update your question". In addition, I don't think there is anything specific to `conf-mode` that is not well-behaved.

Comment: Updated question with the result, thanks!  I take it `conf-mode` is inserting tabs for you when you press the tab key?

Comment: @Malvineous Indeed, enabling `indent-tabs-mode` and setting `tab-width` to a number less than or equal to the column of the next indent point on the last nonblank line (see documentation for function `indent-relative`) results in the `TAB` key inserting literal tab characters on my end. Have you tried starting emacs with the `-Q` option (which forgoes reading your `user-init-file`), adding the `conf-mode-hook` and then opening the file in question? If this works, it means a setting in your `user-init-file` is to blame for the undesired behaviour.

Comment: Two more things to try are (1) adding `(setq indent-line-function #'insert-tab)` to the aforementioned hook and (2) enabling `whitespace-mode` to give a visual indication of whether tabs or spaces are being inserted. I recommend `(progn (setq-default whitespace-style '(face tab-mark)) (global-whitespace-mode))`, which can be evaluated globally and does not need to be placed in a hook.

Comment: `emacs -Q` helped but changed the ident to a combination of tabs and spaces depending on how far the indent needed to be.  Setting `indent-line-function` doesn't quite indent to the level I want, but it only inserts tabs and no spaces so this at least solves the main annoyance for me!  If you want to update your answer to include `indent-line-function` in the `add-hook` section (which is what I ended up doing) then I'll mark this as the accepted answer.  Many thanks!

Comment: @Malvineous Done. I must admit I don't understand where your problem lies anymore. There are three indentation styles I can imagine: (1) spaces all the way, for both indentation and alignment; (2) tabs all the way, in which case alignment is subject to how wide tabs are displayed, i.e. `tab-width`; (3) [smart tabs](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SmartTabs), in which tabs indent and spaces align. Which scheme is used in your file? How is your Emacs configuration failing to enforce this scheme?

Comment: Thanks!  My file is C-style syntax (nginx config file) and between curly braces lines are indented by a single tab.  The original Emacs config I had would indent correctly but only using two spaces instead of a single tab (tab width is 2).  I do have `smarttabs` enabled in `init.el`.

Comment: @Malvineous I am not familiar with smart tabs, and you may anyway want to consider starting a new question on any issues you are facing with such a configuration. By the way, have you looked at [nginx-mode](https://github.com/ajc/nginx-mode)?